# The generateIndexHtml property in @nrwl/webpack:webpack executor options is not working in NX Workspace

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, nx-workspace

I'm working on a legacy react project and I want to migrate it to NX workspace. I have to use a custom `html-webpack-plugin` because the template will be different based on a passed environment variable.

From NX docs if I want to customize the generation of index.html I have to add `generateIndexHtml: false` to `@nrwl/webpack:webpack` executor options. but NX still creates two index.html files. one from NX and another one from my custom webpack config.

The Error I recieve:

```
ERROR in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html
```

my custom HTMLWebpackPlugin:

```
new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(
          `apps/webcp/partners/${env.partnerKey}/assets/index.html`
        ),
        filename: 'index.html',
      }),
```

my @nrwl/webpack:webpack executor object inside project.json`

```
"executor": "@nrwl/webpack:webpack",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "defaultConfiguration": "production",
      "options": {
        "compiler": "babel",
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/webcp",
        "index": "apps/webcp/src/index.html",
        "generateIndexHtml": false,
        "baseHref": "/",
        "main": "apps/webcp/src/app/index.js",
        "polyfills": "apps/webcp/src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "apps/webcp/tsconfig.app.json",
        "scripts": [],
        "webpackConfig": "apps/webcp/webpack.config.js"
      },
```

If I remove my custom HTMLWebpackPlugin. I don't get the error and the project compiles successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same with nx version 14.4.3

Did you see the error when you tried to start webpack dev server, i.e. when you run the "serve" target (e.g. `pnpm nx run my-project:serve`)?

In my case, the error showed up only for `serve` target but not for `build`.

See this issue: [#10263 Web dev-server executor should support generateIndexHtml](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/10263)

The reason is, nx will [add an `IndexHtmlWebpackPlugin` only for webpack dev server](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/9f7df39875d04baa2e8b8f8f12796dea6b38752a/packages/web/src/utils/devserver.config.ts#L50), and currently there's no option to opt out.

The only workaround is to filter out that `IndexHtmlWebpackPlugin` in a custom webpack config.

```js
module.exports = (config, options) => {
  // `devServer` only available for `serve` target
  if (options.configuration === 'development' && 'devServer' in config) {
    // Filter out IndexHtmlWebpackPlugin so that we can use HtmlWebpackPlugin
    config.plugins = config.plugins.filter(
      (plugin) => plugin.constructor.name !== 'IndexHtmlWebpackPlugin'
    );
  }

  config.plugins.push(
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: '/path/to/index.html',
    })
  );

  return config;
};
```